# Write an algorithm to find if user logged in more than 4 times in 30 days?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose you're given sorted timestamps of when User's Login time as array of dates. Find if user logged in more than 4 times in any 30 days.

Example 1:
Array of dates =
1 Jan 12am, 2 jan 12 am, 3 jan 12 am, 4 jan 12 am, 9 feb 12 am

Answer will be no

Example 2:
Array of dates =
1 Jan 12am, 2 jan 12 am, 3 jan 12 am, 4 jan 12 am, 5 jan 12 am

Answer will be yes

I am just looking for pseudo code or algorithm for this problem. Not actual code

My solution

```
   Consider sorted array of n dates
    Iterate thru 0..n-1 consider value as i {
        Iterate thru i+1 till n-1 {
        if arr[j] is within 30 days of arr[i] then loginCount++
        else break;
        if(loginCount == 4)
            return Yes
    }}
    return No;
```

Comment: NinjaCoder, where's your code ???

Comment: This is an algorithm question.

Comment: Sure, but it seems you are asking for something without attempt at the problem yourself

Comment: @NinjaCoder What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please show that you've put effort into finding a solution yourself before asking for help.

Comment: Alright guys. I've written my approach. Hope that helps.

Comment: Your code doesn't work--you have a J appearing from nowhere.  And note that you can do this with only a single loop.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Consider sorted array of n dates
iterate i through dates[0..n-5] {
  Let d1 = date[i]
  Let d2 = date[i+4]
  if d2 < d1 + 30 days then return true
}
return false
```

In other words if the list is sorted then if any two dates that are 5 slots apart are less than 30 days apart then you've met your condition.

First example:

```
d1 = 1 Jan 12AM
d2 = 9 Feb 12AM
Difference is 39 days, so false
```

Second example:

```
d1 = 1 Jan 12AM
d2 = 5 Jan 12AM
Difference is 4 days, so true
```

Don't forget to check this algorithm against your edge cases, because I haven't! :)

Comment: Nice. This would do it in O(n) time.

Comment: Yup, although if your login data is not pre-sorted you obviously have the cost of sorting it first.